# How to create intent for sharing different files types simultaneously for android

Tags: android, android-intent, share, intentfilter

In `AndroidManifest.xml` the following `intent-filter` allows to display the Android app while you select same types to share (all images or all videos).

```xml
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
   <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
   <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But if user select different types of content (image + video) the app with this intent is not is displaying in the share window.

So the question is - what intent should be used to display the app and allow to share files with different types simultaneously?

Thank you!

Comment: Try supporting `android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CommonsWare wrote `android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE` will enable this option.